# Azure Automation - Cannot stop Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I need to stop one of my function apps using Azure Automation. I have created a runbook for it and added this script.

```sh
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

Stop-AzFunctionApp -Name myapp202110 -ResourceGroupName AppRG
```

I'm getting this error.
[image]

Tried this as well,

```
Import-Module Az.Functions
Stop-AzFunctionApp -Name myapp202110 -ResourceGroupName AppRG
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Before you run any cmdlets related to Azure Functions, make sure the `Az.Functions` available in the Modules section.

[image]

The cmdlet `Stop-AzFunctionApp` are included in this module: [Az.Functions](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Functions/2.0.0).

Please import this module and then the functions related operation will work.

[image]